# R - Leaflet map isn't loading in RStudio or Rshiny App - Proxy Authentication Problem

Tags: r, dictionary, shiny, leaflet, r-leaflet

This is my code:

```
map <- mapLeaflet <- leaflet() %>%
  addTiles()
```

And this is the error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 407 
>    (Proxy Authentication Required)

This is how the map appears:

[image: This is how the map appears]

Comment: Hello Jole, if that would be possibile for you, you should add a reproducible example. We could help you more easily :)

Comment: I get the same results when running in RStudio using a VPN.  The code however does run in R.  Any solution to get working in Rstudio when using a VPN would be greatly appreciated.